# white page in cakePhp to run page

Tags: cakephp

I am new in CakePhp I download a project for a server to my local,

But when I run the project see a white page in the browser

I change the connection to DataBase, I have a AllowOverride All in my httpd.conf, 
I have `Configure::write('debug', 2);` in the Core.php, but dont show me any error

But still I see a white page, any idea, I forgot something!

Comment: Probably not the reason for a blank page, try changing security salt and chipper seed values in app/config/core.php

Comment: Also you may want to check both /cakephp/.htaccess and /cakephp/webroot/.htaccess making sure the rewrite bases are correct

Comment: Try deleting tmp folder contents.

Comment: Thanks guys,@Dharmender, @Dan  I do everything, and activate to error_reporting in php init and show me this error Fatal error: CakePHP core could not be found. Check the value of CAKE_CORE_INCLUDE_PATH in APP/webroot/index.php, But the problem If that the project that I download dont have the webroot archive

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Check whether rewrite module is enabled or not in Apache. If not then enable it so that CSS could become visible. Try this and see if it works.